# Beamer metropolis theme standout frame formatting of notes

Tags: beamer, themes, beamer-metropolis

I'm using the [`metropolis`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis) theme for beamer. It has a `standout` feature for frames. But on those frames, the `\note` speaker note pages are rendered incorrectly. The text inherits inherit bold face font and centered alignment. Also the date on the speaker notes is wrongly aligned to the center

Another issue arises when used together with the [`hepnames`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hepnames) package to typeset elementary  particle names. I set the main font back to Computer Modern (`\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`), but with `hepnames` in use, the math font *also* is typeset in bold face.

I tried to fix it in my `\tafelzeit` command by resetting the font, but it does not work for the math font if I use `hepnames`.

Is this a bug in `metropolis` or am I doing something wrong?

Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{hepnames}


\newcommand{\tafelzeit}[1]{%
    \frame[standout]{%
        \emph{Tafelzeit}
        \note{\raggedright\normalfont #1}
    }
}
\newcommand{\themath}{
    Decay width
    \[ \varGamma\big(\APKzero \rightarrow \Ppositron \, \Pmuon\big)  = a + b = 0 \]
}

\title{Metropolis Standout}
\begin{document}
    \section{Decay Width}

    \begin{frame}
        \themath
        \note{\themath}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[standout]
        \themath
        \note{\themath}
    \end{frame}

    \tafelzeit{%
        \themath
    }
\end{document}
```

Everything is correct on normal frames; `[standout]` frames are rendered with bold face and centered alignment; resetting the font does not reset math fonts, when `hepnames` is used.
[image: wrong formatting of speaker notes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround: move the note outside the frame

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{hepnames}

\newcommand{\themath}{
    Decay width
    \[ \varGamma\big(\APKzero \rightarrow \Ppositron \, \Pmuon\big)  = a + b = 0 \]
}

\title{Metropolis Standout}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \themath
        \note{\themath}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[standout]
        \themath
    \end{frame}
    \note{\themath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. Is this the correct way of placing `\note`sich or should I do it just as a work around?

Comment: @Ps0ke I don't think there is the one and only correct way to place the `\note`. Both ways have special cases where they don't work. For my own projects I usually place them inside the frame, because I can then divide them based on overlays with `\note<2>{...}` etc.